# Remove underscore as a word separator in VIM

Tags: search, vim

since yesterday I can't use VIM search efficiently. If my cursor is on the 'f' of 'foo_bar', and I press '*' for searching inside the actual file, it only highlights and therefore searches for 'foo'.

'set iskeyword-=_' is just the opposite I want to do.

Not mentioning, that Ctags is unusable, since I'd have to mark the whole word visually, before searching in my tags.

Has anybody an idea? Hint: It's just yesterday, that I started using the spell check.

Best,
Plattenschieber

Comment: Maybe you should use 'set iskeyword+=_'? I mean, with plus sign.

Comment: Something probably overwrote your `iskeyword` setting. You can check were it was last set by doing `:verbose set iskeyword`

Comment: and you dont just want to do a /foo_bar or ?foo_bar at the command prompt?

Comment: You could of course also just do the right thing and use camelCase instead ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just answering so that it doesn't show up as unanswered in the listing.
Generally you are on the track with your `set iskeyword-=_`. You just need to switch the `-` with a plus, this adds it to the keyword list however.

Why however your spell checker should have any influence on that however is beyond me, I've been using the spell checker (with different languages) for a long time and never experienced this problem.

Does the problem arise again if you turn the spell checker on again?

\Paul

Comment: Hrm.. VimLatex sets `iskeyword`, and it appears to overwrite the value in the .vimrc. You need to `let g:tex_isk='48-57,a-z,A-Z,192-255,_'` instead. Kind of annoying..